# How do I close an OpenPopupPage dialog box from C# code behind an .aspx application page

Tags: 2010, modal-dialog

I am using a Farm application page to display a search/edit modal dialog box. There is an asp button control on that page that I would like to use to close the dialog box. In my research on how to do this I found a suggestion to do this:

window.frameElement.commitPopup();

Is there a way to do the same thing but from the C# code behind the .aspx page instead in a button click handler? I'm not great with javascript so I'm trying to stick to what I know for now.

This is using SharePoint 2010 if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the SharePoint modal dialogs, you can close the modal in a click handler by registering javascript to run after the post back:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // DO STUFF;
    // ...

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "saveSuccess",
        @"<script type='text/javascript'>
            ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(
                function() {
                    var args = {
                        arg1: '" + tbArg1.Text + @"',
                        arg2: '" + tbArg2.Text + @"'
                    };
                    SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK, args);
                }, 'SP.UI.Dialog.js');
        </script>");
}
```